# How to extract text from div element under numerous elements?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

pastebin.com/p9m5tMMw

Hello, I am trying to scrape the data from the website. I have attached the code via paste bin. However the text for example "NET SALES" that I need is under tr then td then div. I am having a hard time extracting that data. If it is NET SALES I would like to get the value of the div inside the 4th td. I have attached the code I have so far. The report generated is also dynamic, so having a hard time identifying a correct id for it. The table id" ctl00_cpMain_rptMain_fixedTable" can be used but I can't get the code to navigate down all those elements to get to the tbody that contains the tr and elements I need. Thank you

```
Sub GetData()
Dim IE As Object
Dim ListOfRows As Object
Dim CellsInsideRow As Object
Dim DivsInsideCell As Object
Dim StrInsideDiv As Object
Dim tRows As Object
Dim tCells As Object
Dim tDivs As Object
Dim Content As Object
Dim ContentArea As Object
Dim ThingInDiv As Object
Dim tThings
Dim t As Integer
Dim s As String
Dim Tbody As Object


Dim ttDivs As HTMLDivElement
Dim DivsInsideOfDivs As Object



Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


'Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer'
Dim HtmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlinput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

' Open Home Page'
With IE

    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://ballout.sage-nexgen.com/report/SDateXParam.aspx?r=204"
    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

End With
' Identify Source Code'
Set HtmlDoc = IE.document

'Mention this bug'

' Input Username and Password'
'On Error Resume Next
'IE.document.forms("aspnetForm").elements("ctl00$cpMain$logMain$UserName").Value = "**********"
'IE.document.forms("aspnetForm").elements("ctl00$cpMain$logMain$Password").Value = "******"
'IE.document.forms("aspnetForm").elements("ctl00$cpMain$logMain$LoginButton").Click

Do While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop
IE.document.forms("aspnetForm").elements("ctl00$cpMain$clbStores$0").Click
Do While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

IE.document.forms("aspnetForm").elements("ctl00$cpMain$StartDate").Value = Range("A1").Text '

Do While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_cpMain_cmdRun2").Click
Do While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop


On Error Resume Next
Set ListOfRows = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
Debug.Print ListOfRows.Length
For Each tRows In ListOfRows
   
    Set CellsInsideRow = tRows.getElementsByTagName("td")
    For Each tCells In CellsInsideRow
        Set DivsInsideCell = tCells.getElementsByTagName("div")
        For Each tDivs In DivsInsideCell
           Set ttDivs = tDivs
           'If Trim(ttDivs.innerText) = "AVERAGE NET SALE" Then
             
            'Debug.Print Trim(ttDivs.innerText)
            'End If
           
        Next tDivs
    Next tCells
Next tRows

        





'Set ListOfRows = Content.getElementsByTagName("tr")
'MsgBox (Len(ListOfRows))
'For Each tRows In ListOfRows
 '  Set CellsInsideRow = tRows.getElementsByTagName("td")
  ' For Each tCells In CellsInsideRow
   '
    '    Set DivsInsideCell = tCells.getElementsByTagName("div")
        
        
        
    'Next tCells
'Next tRows


End Sub
```

[Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt2X3.png)

Comment: Do you need this to be necessarily through VBA?

Comment: I would like to extract the data to inside excel, so I am assuming vba is the only way to do it?

Comment: You can also use Python, doing this through Selenium module is fairly easy.  Then, to interact with excel, you can use OpenPyXl module.

Comment: Providing a sample table with at least 1 row of data would help get you a better answer. `Set td = tRows.cells(3)` will target the correct cell.  I don't know what else you want to do.

Comment: @TinMan I attached the pastebin link for the whole html doctument. I would like to get the "NET SALES" and the value for it and other text I would need. fran J I am not positive how to use those as I am fairly new to this coding thing.

Comment: @tinman I have a table id, from there I would like to access the tbody element that has tr elements, under the tr elements I would like to get the information from the td in rows 3 and 4 =, but inside those tds are div elements that contain the text. I cant seem to navigate between all these tags to get to down to the text inside the div

Comment: If you can check the information image I posted in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is a bit of a mess.  Inside the target HTMLTableCell is another table and many divs inside that tables cels.  I would just split the target `cells.InnerText` by line breaks and process the split data.  It'll be a lot easier than trying to decipher this HTML.

```
Sub ProcessData(IE As InternetExplorerMedium)
    Const AverageNetSalesText As String = "AVERAGE NET SALE"
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument, tbl As HTMLTable, ListRows As Object, tr As HTMLTableRow, td As HTMLTableCell
    Dim data As Variant
    Set doc = IE.Document
    Set tbl = doc.getElementById("ctl00_cpMain_rptMain_fixedTable")
    Set ListRows = tbl.getElementsByTagName("TR")

    For Each tr In ListRows
        If tr.Cells.Length >= 2 Then
            Set td = tr.Cells(2)
            If Not td Is Nothing Then
                If InStr(td.innerText, "AVERAGE") > 0 Then
                    data = Split(td.innerText, vbNewLine)

                    Dim AverageNetSales As Single
                    If UBound(data) >= 15 Then
                        If InStr(data(15), AverageNetSalesText) > 0 Then
                            data(15) = Trim(data(15))
                            AverageNetSales = Right(data(15), Len(data(15)) - Len(AverageNetSalesText))
                            'Do something
                            Range("A17") = AverageNetSales
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for this are you locating the Average Net Sale? I would like to get the text and the total for example Net sales in A17 and the $ amount in B17 which is $2485.74

Comment: Right now nothing is being generated I am not getting and information back or any errors when I paste your code in. How can I get it to enter the information into excel cell A17 for example

Comment: Thank you for your help, It is still not returning any data. I copied and pasted the code you provided then added the range line under 'Do something and no errors come up but cell A17 has no information in it.

Comment: yes but these IDs change with different reports. These reports are generated based on the date entered

Answer (score 0):

You have nested tables but in your html there is a table with id `content` that has all the info. You can gather the rows (`tr`) in that table and loop looking for the string of interest. If you use `.innerText` on the row you will get the financial amount along with the text description. Otherwise, you can extract the sub info from the `td` elements within the row. Something like the following:

```
Dim html As HTMLDocument, tableRows As Object, i As Long, rowOfInterest As Object
Set html = ie.document
Dim a As Object
Set tableRows = html.querySelectorAll("#content tr")
For i = 0 To tableRows.Length - 1
    If InStr(tableRows.Item(i).innerText, "NET SALES") > 0 Then
        Set rowOfInterest = tableRows.Item(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If Not rowOfInterest Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print tableRows.Item(i).innerText
    Debug.Print tableRows.Item(i).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText
End If
```

Sample of the row info:

[image]

The values are populated through javascript so you need to allow enough time for population.

Comment: On my immediate window after that code I still get no values whatsoever not even a text

Comment: Is tableRows.Length = 0 ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have been messing this for like a month and I have tried numerous things and still can not seem to generate any information.

Comment: I put debug.print tableRows.Length and I got nothing in the immediate window

Comment: you should get something. Are you stepping through with F8? Stop after the line Set tableRows = html.querySelectorAll("#content tr") and then put ?tableRows.length in the immediate window and press enter

Comment: after that the immediate window is still blank

Comment: so after I did that now I get "null"

Comment: I need to see your implementation. You should get an integer. 0 is the lowest number I would expect.